# How to get value from input fields with two dimensional arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have input fields that are dynamically created it is like this:

```
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][123]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][123]" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][167]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][167]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][167]" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][166]" class="form-control" required="">
```

Now i have 123, 167, 166 from my previous calculations, now i want to get all the fields with 163, 167, 166 for that i'm using following code, where key contains 123, 167, 166 as example it can contain more or any other value too :

```
 foreach ($request->input('attribute_value.*'.$key)  as $key => $value) {

                      print_r($key);
                      print_r($val);

                    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to print the first dimension indices:

```
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[0][123]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[1][123]" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[0][167]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[1][167]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[2][167]" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[0][166]" class="form-control" required="">
```

Or just make [] for the second dimension:

```
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[123][]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[123][]" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[167][]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[167][]" class="form-control" required="">
<input type="text" name="attribute_value[167][]" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[166][]" class="form-control" required="">

// in controller
foreach ($request->input('attribute_value')  as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it create any issue if i leave second indeces blank rather than first?

Comment: the last indices will passed automatically with array order 0,1,...
But the first will not